# Prevent generation of WM_MOUSEMOVE after popup window is shown/hidden

Tags: winapi, mouseevent, popupwindow, user32, hwnd

I have encountered an annoying problem. When the mouse pointer is positioned over my main window and the owning popup window is shown (see example below) or is made invisible a `WM_MOUSEMOVE` message is generated each time even if the mouse has not been moved. For several reasons it can't be tolerated in my case.

```
    hWnd = CreateWindowEx(0, wcx.lpszClassName, L"Demo", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, nullptr, 0, hInstance, nullptr);
    HWND hWndPopupTest = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_NOACTIVATE | WS_EX_TOPMOST, L"Static", L"DemoPopup", WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE, 10, 10, 100, 100, hWnd, 0, hInstance, nullptr);
    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
    ShowWindow(hWndPopup, SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE);
    Sleep(1000);
    ShowWindow(hWndPopup, SW_HIDE);
```

The same behavior occurs when `ReleaseCapture` is called. Is this a feature that can be disabled? Is it a known "problem" or is there a workaround?

**Edit: Dirty Workaround**

In (main) window procedure we could test if the mouse position has changed since last `WM_MOUSEMOVE`. If the position has not changed it must be because wither a popup window was shown/hidden or a some window capture was released.

Comment: It cannot be disabled.  Actually important, it ensures that the cursor shape is correct.  You'll have to work around it.

Comment: Is this behavior documented somewhere?

Comment: [Why do I get spurious WM_MOUSEMOVE messages?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031001-00/?p=42343), [Sure, I can get spurious WM_MOUSEMOVE messages, but why do they keep streaming in?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090617-00/?p=17863), and [Why do I get a spurious WM_MOUSEMOVE message whenever Resource Manager is running?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160616-00/?p=93685).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information provided here (thank you @IInspectable) my general solution would be to detect if the given point is a real point by looking in mouse position history with `GetMouseMovePointsEx`. If no point is found it means no valid movement occurred.

```
    POINT CurrentPoint{GET_X_LPARAM(lParam), GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam)};
    MapWindowPoints(hWnd, nullptr, &CurrentPoint, 1);
    MOUSEMOVEPOINT mmpi = {
        CurrentPoint.x, CurrentPoint.y, GetTickCount(), 0
    };
    MOUSEMOVEPOINT mmpo = {0};
    if (GetMouseMovePointsEx(sizeof(mmpi), &mmpi, &mmpo, 1, GMMP_USE_DISPLAY_POINTS) > 0) {
        MyInstance->HandleMouseMove(POINT{GET_X_LPARAM(lParam), GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam)}, wParam);
    } else {
        // No mouse point found in history, so couldn't be a valid point
    }
```